# Show file history with tags?

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to show the history of a file - with each commit showing which tags it belongs to?

Every time we upgrade our database, one file is updated with the new schema version. Often, I'll have a database (which has the schema version in a settings table) and I'd like to look at the commits (with that version number) and see what releases (tags) they belong to.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this on GitHub, but I'm happy if there's something I can do on the command line.

**Update**

I created an Powershell version of @phd's script:

```
$results = $(git rev-list -5 master -- README.rst)

foreach ( $item in $results ) { 
  git describe $item --tags; 
  git show $item --no-patch 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line with [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log --decorate -- filename
```

For every commit in the log `--decorate` prints tags and branches the commit belongs to.

For example, log for file `README.rst` from [SQLObject](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject):

```
$ git log --decorate -4 -- README.rst
commit 39b3cd4
Author: Oleg Broytman <phd@phdru.name>
Date:   Sat Feb 24 19:10:59 2018 +0300

    Prepare for the next release

    [skip ci]

commit 0fd1c21 (tag: 3.6.0)
Author: Oleg Broytman <phd@phdru.name>
Date:   Sat Feb 24 18:50:36 2018 +0300

    Release 3.6.0

commit 0684a9b (tag: 3.5.0)
Author: Oleg Broytman <phd@phdru.name>
Date:   Wed Nov 15 16:47:04 2017 +0300

    SQLObject 3.5.0 released 15 Nov 2017

commit 623a580 (tag: 3.4.0)
Author: Oleg Broytman <phd@phdru.name>
Date:   Sat Aug 5 19:30:51 2017 +0300

    Release 3.4.0
```

*Upd*. If the commits are not tagged `git log --decorate` cannot show the nearest tag. `git describe` can but it cannot list commits. So you have to list commits using `git rev-list` (plumbing command behind `git log` and other commands) and `git describe`:

```
$ git rev-list -5 master -- README.rst | xargs git describe
3.6.0-1-g39b3cd4
3.6.0
3.5.0
3.4.0
3.3.0-2-g3d2bf5a
```

But then you loose commit's hashes and content. You need to write a script to show all information at once. Something like that:

```
for H in $(git rev-list -5 master -- README.rst); do
    git describe $H; git show $H
done
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't seem to show any tags (it shows Commit, Author, Date and Comment). Do I need to fetch from remote. I've tried `git fetch --tags` already

Comment: First list tags with `git tag --list` — are there any tags at all? Does the file belong to some tagged commits?

Comment: When I run `git tag --list` - yes it does. All the tags in our repo are GitHub releases - which is what I see in this list

Comment: Okay, I think I know what's happening. Non of the commits are a commit that's chosen for a tag - therefore there is no tag annotation?

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'd like to see the most relevant tag to each commit (even ones that haven't been tagged). Considering tags are not branches, is such a thing possible?